# creating custom GROK pattern in Log stash

Tags: logstash, grok

I want to create Logstash custom pattern and for that need a directory called pattern and file.
but what is the extension of that file

Comment: You need to provide more information about what your problem is. You want to use a file with custom grok patterns on it? Is that right?

Comment: yes. but is it normal text file

Comment: 2021-07-26 19:21:08,903 INFO com.tdg.box.data.writer.BoxDataItemProcessor [Thread-6]                     name:1 id:70897892481 is a folder. total folder:115177 userid:14960923573 user folder count:29379

Comment: this is log line i want field for date info and class name and thread